# geckodriver with Selenium 3.0 driver.get() dosnt navigate to the URL

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, web-application, selenium3

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","D:\\selenium\\New folder\\geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Answer (score 3):

Selenium recently launched its one of the major release, i.e., Selenium 3 – beta. You can download it from here-
[Download Selenium 3.0-Beta](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) .

In this new version, one of the major change is the way Mozilla Firefox Browser is invoked and for that **GeckoDriver** is necessary for invoking Firefox Browser.
Gecko Driver can be downloaded from [Here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

> The minimum version of Mozilla required for Selenium 3 is **Firefox-48 and above.**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c://workspace//libs//geckodriver.exe"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

String url = "http://www.google.com";

/* To Maximize the window */
driver.manage().window().maximize();

/* To delete all the cookies of the browser */
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

/* To navigate to a particular URL */
driver.get(url);
```

This will definitely work..

Answer (score 1):

If your using eclipse try switching the \\ to // in your path to the geckodriver. You also need to change the string inside the `setProperty` to `webdriver.gecko.driver`:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D://selenium//New folder//geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Also make sure that you have the correct version of firefox for the geckodriver.